# I got an error when using linear_model.LogisticRegression

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, error-handling, linear-regression

I got an error when using linear_model.LogisticRegression.
Is it related to data types of X and y?
I'm using Python 3.8 64bit and SkLearn version: 1.2.0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

# datat generation

m = 100
w0 = -6
w = np.array([[2], [1]])
X = np.hstack([4*np.random.rand(m,1), 4*np.random.rand(m,1)])

w = np.asmatrix(w)
X = np.asmatrix(X)

y = 1/(1 + np.exp(-w0-X*w)) > 0.5 

C1 = np.where(y == True)[0]
C0 = np.where(y == False)[0]

y = np.empty([m,1])
y[C1] = 1
y[C0] = 0

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)


from sklearn import linear_model

clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
clf.fit(X, np.ravel(y))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poTcm.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting may be related to the data types of X and y. The fit method of the LogisticRegression class expects the input to be in the form of numpy arrays or pandas dataframes.

It seems that in your code, X and y are of type numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix.
You can convert them to numpy arrays using the np.array() function.

```
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

You also need to make sure that the dimensions of X and y match, so that each row of X corresponds to a single observation and each element of y corresponds to the label of the corresponding observation.

Additionally, in your code you are using the function 'np.ravel(y)' to flatten y into a 1-D array, but it's unnecessary. If the y is a 1-D array it will work fine.

Also, you can check that you have the correct version of sklearn installed, and in case you find any compatibility issues you can update your sklearn library.

Comment: Thank you so much. I works well after I changed X as array.

Comment: No problem! Just please mark my answer as the correct one! Have a good one!